# How to compile and link boost libraries within Eclipse on Oracle Linux

Tags: c++, boost, linker, g++

Having trouble figuring out how to compile and link a simple boost program that just includes some boost libraries.

The code is as follows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    return 0;
}
```

Note to the moderators: there are a lot of posts on SO asking similar questions.  However, I didn't find one that completely solved my issue (the key insight I was missing was that I needed to install `boost-devel`).  Thus, I created this Q&A.

Answer (score -1):

Here are the steps necessary to compile your program

1. Install `boost` and `boost-devel`

   sudo yum install boost # installs the libraries for linking
   sudo yum install boost-devel # installs the header files for you to include for compilation
2. The command you're trying to get Eclipse to produce is the following:

   g++ net-server.cpp -I /usr/include -L/usr/lib64/ -lboost_system

The `-L/usr/lib64` is actually unnecessary, but I include it for the reader, since it allows the reader more easily understand the relationship between the `-l` inclusion and the `-L/usr/lib64` that's by default included in Oracle Linux (probably RHEL too).

The `-I /usr/include` is also unnecessary, but it's included to make it clear to the reader where the `boost/array.hpp` etc. files are coming from for the compilation phase.

3. To get Eclipse to produce that command

   - Go to project > properties
   - Choose the build you wish to configure (you'll probably want to do it for both the "Debug" and "Release" builds, but maybe you just have one)
   - Go to the "Cross G++ Linker" > Libraries.
   - In the Libraries section, click on the `+` icon and add the `boost_system` library.

Heads up that I chose the "cross gcc compilation" option instead of the Linux cross-compile option.  This is actually from within Nvidia's version of Eclipse (distributed with CUDA as "Eclipse Nsight"), so the instructions for the non-Nvidia version of Eclipse may vary a bit.

Comment: You may also need the `pthread` library and to enable c++11 support.

Comment: Also, as you use more boost libraries, you'll need to link those as well.  E.g., add `boost_thread`.